Using SqlParameter with DataTable.Compute
Can SqlParameter only be used with SqlCommand? I would like to use parameters within the DataTable.Compute() function, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that correctly.
Here is my partial function:
private void UpdateDeptBudget(int departmentId, int yearCode, int orderNum)
{
    // get the order total
    using (conn)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["OrderItems"];

        object orderTotal = dt.Compute("SUM(itemTotal)", "orderId = " + orderNum);                                                                                             
        // .
        // .
        // .
    }
}


As an alternative, you could also achieve your goal using  Linq on your datatable, see the answer to this question: LINQ query on a DataTable

I would like to use parameters within the DataTable.Compute() function - don't bother, it's not an injection risk

The DataSet in the function is a brand-new object, empty, and does not have any data tables. You need to fill it with the required tables and data to compute. Consider executing a database SUM query instead.

@flackoverstow That's not true, it's just not "breakout-able" ie you can't execute arbitrary code, but you can get incorrect results or cause an exception.

DataTable.Compute is very primitive, don't use it with complex inputs or user inputs. In fact, don't use DataTable at all if you can, use a proper object model with LINQ.

Hi Amy, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that solutions, even unsatisfactory workarounds, go in answers, not in edits to the question. Please post the code you are going with in an answer below.

"Can SqlParameter only be used with SqlCommand?" Yes, SqlParameterCollection's class is part of the SqlCommand class. As for your example code, that might work, if orderNum were a string; .Compute() takes two strings, so passing an int will always cause problems there.

@Charlieface injectable (with an int? really?) but not a risk, then? :)

@flackoverstow True, but wait til someone tries to use it with user-inputted strings... As far as I'm aware it's impossible to execute arbitrary code, but if you want to take that risk then you need to read through the source code to be sure.

This is simple as you proceed
There are several ways to handle this issue. As you proceeded with something I just carry it to end.
        private void btnDataTableCompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5]
            {
                new DataColumn("OrderID", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("ProductName", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Qty", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Price", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(int))
            });
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "TV", 1, 45000, 4500);
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Mobile", 1, 32000, 32000);
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Laptop", 2, 90000, 180000);
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Keyboard", 2, 3300, 6600);
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "WashingMachine", 3, 1800, 5400);
           
            decimal TotVal = OrderBalance(2, dt);
        }

        private static decimal OrderBalance(int mOrderID, DataTable dtOrder)
        {
            Decimal TotalValue = dtOrder.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int>("OrderID") == mOrderID).Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Amount"));
            return TotalValue;
        }

Implemented the above code on .Net Framework 4.7.2
